# HTML5 Canvas Composition

Tags: image, html5-canvas, photo

I'm trying to get my head around canvas compostion.  I'm trying to create a simple scene where there are (probably) 3 layers.  The bottom layer takes up the whole canvas and might be a photograph of a users living room wall.  The top layer can be multiple picture frames that the user can move around on the wall to see the effect.  Between those two layers are user uploaded pictures that need to appear underneath the frames (so that the image is 'framed') but on top of the background image.  The frame obviously has a transparent cutout.  The problem arises when the picture in the middle layer is sized so that the edges are visible around the edge of the frame as well as in the middle.  How to show the picture inside of the frame but not outside?  I was wondering about another layer between the frame and pictures that also shows the background but is transparent only where the frame cutout is. Is that possible?

Comment: ctx.drawImage() has some optional parameters to do with the destination width and height (dWidth and dHeight on the MDN docs), so can't you set those so the image won't exceed the dimensions of the frame? Or perhaps use the sWidth and sHeight to get a sub-rectangle of the source image if some cropping is required?

Comment: I'll look into that. thx.